# unable to compile ChromeOption options.addarguments("--start-maximized") inside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, chrome-options

Unable to compile code line  "options.addarguments("--start-maximized") ", using selinum 3.0.1 and using ChromDriver_win32 latest version and eclispe  Mars.. Let me know what i am missing.  I am able to compile and run my test without options..

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
 import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

 public class IRSLabTestCase {
    WebDriver driver1=  new ChromeDriver();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); //--> this line not getting     compiled.
    driver1 = new ChromeDriver(options);'
}
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work because you can only initialize members in a class.
To do operations on them you have to put it in a function or do those in a constructor.

You are initializing `driver1` object twice .You have to learn java basics.Else you can't proceed further.

You can do like below.

```
public class IRSLabTestCase {

    WebDriver driver1;
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();      

    public IRSLabTestCase(){
         options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
         driver1 = new ChromeDriver(options);'
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does the job, but you've left your answer incomplete, and there's no need for "obviously".

Comment: @MarkLapierre there is some connectivity issue which lead to that.Thanks I've edited.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. when i tried it worked right after i posted my initial message . I didn't understood the reason. Thanks again. driver1 is a copy paste issue.

Answer (score -1):

**Instead of chrome options you should try this:**

```
ChromeDriver driver;  
driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

or

```
           ChromeOptionsoptions =new  ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```